# 32 bit app not receiving WM_MOUSEHWHEEL messages

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user32

I'm posting this in case someone else stumbles across this weirdness.

Microsoft's Intellimouse will send wm_mousewheel messages to an inactive window but not wm_mousehwheel messages. The wm_mousehwheel messages only go to an active window.

It took me quite awhile to realize that the wm_mouseHwheel messages were being sent to a status window I have floating over my main window whereas the vertical wm_mousewheel messages showed up in my main window.

No idea why the Intellimouse driver treats horizontal scrolling differently than vertical scrolling but there it is.

Comment: What is the question? The information contained here is stated in the documentation. It almost reads like a cautionary tale of what happens when you don't read documentation.

Comment: There's a subtle distinction in the MSDN docs between `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` and `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL`.  `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` is "Sent to the **focus** window when the mouse wheel is rotated."  `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` is "
Sent to the **active** window when the mouse's horizontal scroll wheel is tilted or rotated."

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Selbie points out the issue - I reread and reread the docs and missed the single adjective difference between the two messages. You have to be a *very* careful reader to see the difference of a single word in the docs. The original post started as a question as I had yet to realize the difference between the two message targets. It evolved into a self-answering question when I spotted the difference. As it took me some time to see the distinction, I thought it worth mentioning for people who run into the same issue down the road.